# PySpark/HIVE: append to an existing table

Tags: python, apache-spark, hive, pyspark

Really basic question pyspark/hive question:

How do I append to an existing table? My attempt is below

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
conf_init = SparkConf().setAppName('pyspark2')
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf_init)
hive_cxt = HiveContext(sc)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,0], 'b':[0,0]})
sdf = hive_cxt.createDataFrame(df)
sdf.write.mode('overwrite').saveAsTable('database.table') #this line works

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1], 'b':[2,2,2]})
sdf = hive_cxt.createDataFrame(df)
sdf.write.mode('append').saveAsTable('database.table') #this line does not work
#sdf.write.insertInto('database.table',overwrite = False) #this line does not work
```

Thanks!
Sam

Comment: `sdf.write.mode('append')` is the correct way to append to a Hive table. In  PySpark 2.2.0, the example above works as expected. Do you get any error messages ?

Comment: Hmm. I'm using the same version. I get a long list of error messages, but I think this is the main one: `IllegalArgumentException: 'Expected exactly one path to be specified, but got: '`

Comment: It sounds like a Hive configuration issue. Does it work if you add  `.option("path", "hdfs://....")` to the writes ?

Comment: Thanks for your help! Stupid question, how do get the path to hdfs is? (I'm showing what a newbie I am! I Googled it, but the results aren't super helpful.)

Comment: The HDFS path, if you have it configured, can be found in the Master WebUI (port 8080) of Spark. Your error message suggest that path is empty though.

Comment: @SamShort, I'm trying to append data to an existing hive table with this code - `testdf.write.mode("append").format("parquet").saveAsTable("mydb.mytable")`. But I get the error - `py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o109.saveAsTable.
: java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator`. Can you help here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems using option('overwrite') was causing the problem; it drops the table and then recreates a new one. If I do the following, everything works fine:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext

conf_init = SparkConf().setAppName('pyspark2')
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf_init)
print(sc.version)
hive_cxt = HiveContext(sc)
hive_cxt.sql('USE database')

query = """
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table (a int, b int)
        STORED AS parquet
        """
hive_cxt.sql(query)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,0], 'b':[0,0]})
sdf = hive_cxt.createDataFrame(df)
sdf.write.mode('append').format('hive').saveAsTable('table')

query = """
        SELECT *
        FROM   table
        """
df = hive_cxt.sql(query)
df = df.toPandas()
print(df) # successfully pull the data in table

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1], 'b':[2,2,2]})
sdf = hive_cxt.createDataFrame(df)
sdf.write.mode('append').format('hive').saveAsTable('table')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think previously you forgot use the format option which caused the issue for you when you are trying to append and not overwrite like you mentioned above.